# What is the difference between TotalFreeSpace and AvailableFreeSpace

Tags: c#, .net

Unable to understand the difference between `TotalFreeSpace` and `AvailableFreeSpace`

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The [documentation on `DriveInfo.TotalFreeSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.totalfreespace.aspx) and [on `DriveInfo.AvailableFreeSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.availablefreespace.aspx) tell you respectively:

> ### Remarks (`TotalFreeSpace`)
>
> This property indicates the total amount of free space available on the drive, not just what is available to the current user.

> ### Remarks (`AvailableFreeSpace`)
>
> This property indicates the amount of free space available on the drive. Note that this number may be different from the [TotalFreeSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.totalfreespace.aspx) number because this property takes into account disk quotas.

Answer (score 9):

According to MSDN:

[TotalFreeSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.totalfreespace.aspx)

> This property indicates the total amount of free space available on
>   the drive, **not just what is available to the current user**.