# DriveInfo.TotalSize does not indicate correct value

Tags: c#

`DriveInfo.TotalSize` does not indicate the correct value, or possibly does but in my case its invalid to use.

I need to find the total size of the drive however if the drive is completely empty... why is it that when spitting out a messagebox with the AvailableFreeSpace and the TotalSize results in two different values?

```
if (drive.AvailableFreeSpace != drive.TotalSize) { /* copy data to another drive. */ }
```

Comment: Does this question provide your answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7275806/what-is-the-difference-between-totalfreespace-and-availablefreespace

Comment: No, I want to know the total size so that I can take (totalsize - availablefreespace).

Comment: Probably best to add some code and demonstrate how the values are incorrect then.

Comment: A *formatted* drive requires overhead for the file system.  Which takes space away to store the file index.  Other storage you might now see is the recycle bin.  Simple enumerate the root directory to see files you might want to copy.

Comment: That was my backup plan, just wanted to avoid the overhead. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the MSDN there is a note about `AvialableFreeSpace` property, it tells:

> This property indicates the amount of free space available on the
>   drive. Note that this number may be different from the TotalFreeSpace
>   number because this property takes into account disk quotas.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.availablefreespace.aspx

Comment: I've read through the documentation prior, but is there any way to check total size of the drive where if empty... the two properties equal the same result? PS: Your avatar is awesome.

Comment: It's weird, I'll check the reason why PS Thanks a lot :-)

Comment: You need to get the disk free space right? Can you post your bad values?

Comment: Currently the drive is empty, AvailableFreeSpace returns 3984584704 and TotalSize returns 3984588800.